# Image processing in iOS + C++ in iphone app

Tags: c++, objective-c, xcode, class, ios5

My first question is that if I write a class in C++ using opencv library to detect any object in an image and call that c++ class in objective-C (xcode project) then will this technique work?

and

Second question is that how I can add **c/c++** class in my **iphone app project** and use it in my traditional ViewController Class.

**What I have done till now is uder**

: Created a TabView Application with one ViewController.
: Added a Push Button in that ViewController.
: Added a File.c class which is just printing string.
: Imported "File.c" in my ViewController.h and ViewController.m class like

**MY ViewController.h class**

```
#import <UIkit/UIkit.h>
#import "file.c"
```

**MY ViewController.m class**

```
#import "FirstViewController.h"
#import "File.c"
```

now on action of the push button I want to call that C class that I have already added in the project.
I am hoping to get good and beneficial answers.

Regards

Comment: @SpencerWong :: If my c/c++ class in just printing a line on screen and I have added a button in my ViewController class and all what I want is that on pushing button my C/C++ class start working. So how to do so?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**File.c**

```
#ifndef testC_File_c
#define testC_File_c
#include <stdio.h>
void say_hello() {
    printf("Hello World!");
}
#endif
```

**ViewController.h**

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface ViewController : UIViewController
- (IBAction) buttonDown:(id)sender;
@end
```

**ViewController.mm**

```
#import "ViewController.h"
#include "File.c"
@interface ViewController ()

@end

@implementation ViewController

- (IBAction) buttonDown:(id)sender
{
    say_hello();
}
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
}
- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
}

@end
```

Comment: :: Thanks for answering my question. Can you please review my question. I shall be thankful to you.